# How can I fix a UnicodeDecodeError when reading files

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-unicode, python-3.8

So I am trying to read a certain line from a file, but every time I try I get a unicode decode error saying codec cant decode it. Here is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername(changed for privacy)/Documents/Programming project/project.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(f.readline())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

I have also tried f.read commands with the same results. Here is my full code:

```
score = 0
i = 1
lives = 2
password = "p4ssw0rd"
points = 0
f = open("Songs.docx", "r")
print(f.readline()) #where the error arises
playerName = input("Welcome to the game! Please enter your name: ")
print("Hi, " + playerName + "!")
while i < 3:
    passwordAttempt = input("Please enter the password to play: ")
    if passwordAttempt == password:
        print("Correct passcode")      print("**********************************************************")
        break
    else:
        i = i - 1
        print("Incorrect password. Please try again.")
print("So this is how the game works")
print("A random song will be chosen. You will be given the name of the artist and the first letter of the song name.")
print("You must try and guess the name of the song based off this.")
print("If you are correct on your first attempt, you get 3 points. If correct on your second try, you'll receive 1 point.")
print("If you are incorrect on your second try then it's game over. Try and score as many points as you can!")
wannaPlay = input("So, " + playerName + ", do you still wanna play? YES or NO (all uppercase) ")
if wannaPlay == "YES":
    pass
elif wannaPlay == "NO":
    print("Well this was a waste of time.")
    import sys
    sys.exit("farewell")
else:
    print("You didnt type YES or NO so you've gotta GO.")
    import sys
    sys.exit("Bye")
print("Just checking, just checking. Now lets get on with it.")
print("**************************************************************")
```

to clarify this is in Python 3.8.2. What can I do to solve this error? Also I am new to using stack overflow so sorry if I didn't use the correct format. I also did use correct indentation but for some reason it shows up here in one big block

Comment: Welcome to the site! You're not going to be able to read a docx file with `open` as this is a proprietary Microsoft Word format. You should save the file as a csv or txt file to make things easier and then work with that.

Comment: There are libraries like [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that are able to read a subset of docx documents.